# CMake: "The C compiler identification is unknown" in Windows SDK

Tags: cmake

This is the first time I've come across CMake. When I follow CMake instructions to extract a C# project, it give the below error.

```
Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.15063.
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

I tried to fix the error by googling, but not able to find the problem yet. Can someone please help me.

Note:
I am running CMake on a Windows 10 computer, that has Windows 8.1 SDK, Visual studio 2015, 2017 installed.

Comment: Have you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619296/cmake-does-not-find-visual-c-compiler) and answers for it? Which answer(s) have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with a very similar system configuration. In my case, it appears to have been related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028259/cmake-windows-10-sdk) which pointed me to [this bug report](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15831).

So the fix (for me) was to update CMake:

1. Uninstall your current version of CMake.
   **If you installed it using an installer script, you'll need to run the uninstaller as noted on CMake.org.**

   > Installer tool has changed. Uninstall CMake 3.4 or lower first!

   If you installed a zipped portable version, you can simply delete it and/or move it out of your `PATH` environment variable.
2. Download the [latest CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) (at time of writing, 3.14.5). This time I opted to install the zipped version and manually add it to my `PATH` environment variable since I only ever use CMake from command prompt anyway, but you're welcome to use the MSI instead.

And after that everything worked fine! Hope this helps.