# The C and CXX compiler identification is unknown

Tags: c++, cmake

I created a cocos2d project and when I want to execute the cmake command I got this problem

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Game/MyGame/proj.win32/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Game/MyGame/proj.win32/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Do you have a C or C++ compiler installed on your system? Is the path to those compiler executables set as PATH environment variable?

Comment: yes i have it ` C:\Users\me>where gcc
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe

C:\Users\me>where g++
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe `

Comment: The line `-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.` suggests that you configure your project for Visual Studio. That tool cannot use MinGW compiler. For configure the project for MinGW, select [MinGW Makefiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/MinGW%20Makefiles.html) generator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake does not find Visual C++ compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619296/cmake-does-not-find-visual-c-compiler)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for hours and found out a solution finally:

- step 1: activate visual studio
- step 2: run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat` to set up enviroment. (modify the path to fit your system)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the CMakeError.log, as indicated in the error message

```
See also "D:/Game/MyGame/proj.win32/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Next, consult various duplicates of this question to see suggestions how to respond to what you find in the log

- [CMake does not find Visual C++ compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619296/cmake-does-not-find-visual-c-compiler)
- [CMake: "The C compiler identification is unknown" in Windows SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288240/cmake-the-c-compiler-identification-is-unknown-in-windows-sdk)
- ...